# Android Google Maps Displays Blank Grid

Tags: android, google-maps, api-key

I've seen this question asked numerous times, but none of the solutions seem to work for me.

I'm trying to make an activity in my app that displays a google map, but when I run my app in an AVD, the map currently only displays blank tiles.

I believe that I have properly generated a debug API key using the command:

```
keytool -v -list -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

and entering the SHA1 key into the Google API Access request.  I've also included the mapview with key in my activity's xml, plus the required isRouteDisplayed method in the activity class.

Also, logcat's error message says that com.google.android.gms has an error opening trace file: No such file or directory(2).  However, it doesn't specify what file is missing.

My manifest file is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="..."
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

<uses-feature
  android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
  android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity>
        ....some activities
    </activity>


</application>
```

Could someone point me in a direction as to where the problem is occurring?  Thanks!

Comment: You MUST add <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="your_api_key"/> as a child of the <application> element in your Manifest.xml. I can not find that in your code above. First check it.

Comment: Second, your API key don't need to be the key gained through MD5 or SHA1. Because it's OK for you to use the default key found in your API console in order just only to test your app : it is "Key for browser apps (with referers)" shown in your API console.

Comment: Third, set your project to the "Google APIs" target, not "Android x.x", To do so, right-click on your project in Eclipse and click Properties > Android > Project Build Target where you can set it. When you run your project on the emulator, you MUST set the AVD to the "Google APIs" target, not "Android x.x", as well.

Answer (score 1):

> and entering the SHA1 key into the Google API Access request

you need to provide MD5 key.

Instructions on the [signup page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey#getfingerprint) are not quite correct. To get MD5 fingerprint, add `-v` option to your command:

```
keytool -v -list -alias alias_name -keystore my-release-key.keystore
```

Comment: I tried using my MD5 key, but it said that I had an invalid input.  It seems like with Android GMaps V2, they only accept SHA1 keys.  I found a couple places that mentioned something about Gmaps not working on an emulator.  When I get ahold of a development phone, I'll see if that might be causing the problem.  Thanks for your help!